# How can i remove this space from a SwiftUI custom CustomTabBar

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

You can see the issue in the image below there is a space above the                 Rectangle with a teal Color that I cant remove so that code can match the design.

[image: image showing the issue]
You can replicate the issue using the code below:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DatemeApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
        }
    }
}
```

and

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RootView: View {
    @StateObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
    var body: some View {
        CustomTabBar(viewRouter: viewRouter)
    }
}

struct RootView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RootView()
    }
}



struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            SectionView()
            SectionView()
            SectionView()
            SectionView()
            SectionView()
        }
    }
}

struct SectionView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack( pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                    ForEach(0..<8) { _ in
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 132, height: 168)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.background(Color.green)
    }
}

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentPage: Page = .home
}


enum Page {
    case home
    case liked
    case records
    case user
}


struct CustomTabBar: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                switch viewRouter.currentPage {
                case .home:
                    HomeView()
                        .background(Color.green)
                case .liked:
                    Text("Msg")
                case .records:
                    Text("Cal")
                case .user:
                    Text("People")
                }
                Spacer()
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.teal)
                    .frame(height: 2)
                ZStack {
                    HStack {
                        TabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .home, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "house.fill", tabName: "Home")
                        TabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .liked, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "ellipsis.message.fill", tabName: "Msg")
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.yellow, Color.teal)
                            .offset(y: -geometry.size.height / 13.5)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print("Plus Button Tapped")
                            }
                        TabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .records, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "calendar", tabName: "Cal")
                        TabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .user, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "person", tabName: "People")
                    }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height/8)
                }
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
    }
}

struct TabBarIcon: View {
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    let assignedPage: Page
    
    let width, height: CGFloat
    let systemIconName, tabName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: systemIconName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
            //                .padding(.top, 10)
            Text(tabName)
                .font(.footnote)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, -4)
        .onTapGesture {
            viewRouter.currentPage = assignedPage
        }
        .foregroundColor(viewRouter.currentPage == assignedPage ? Color(UIColor(hue:0.713, saturation:0.532, brightness:0.393, alpha:1.000)) : Color(UIColor(hue:0.648, saturation:0.421, brightness:0.705, alpha:1.000)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question. But the `@StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter` inside of `TabBarIcon` should be an `@ObservedObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 elemnts in your `CustomTabBar`s `VStack` that cause this. Remove:

```
Spacer()
Rectangle()
    .fill(Color.teal)
    .frame(height: 2)
```

A spacer has a minimum height, also the Rectange has an explicit height of 2.